# using str.contains function to multiply column by

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to multiply a coefic number in a column but only for matches using string contains or regex match.

So I want to mutiply only for name contain "Texas" and keep other values not changed.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["texas_154_a", "texas_west_b", "New_York"], 
"Value":[10, 12, 25]})
```

Code:

```
Coefic = 10

df.Value= df.Value[df['Name'].str.contains((f'texas'))] * Coefic
```

output:

```
Name              Value 

"texas_154_a"     100
"texas_west_b"    120
"New_York"],      NaN
```

Desired output:

```
Name              Value 

"texas_154_a"     100
"texas_west_b"    120
"New_York"],      25
```

Comment: You are setting a filtered version of a series to a series. So, the reesults that you filtered out will be `NaN`. you can use `df.Value = df.Value.mask(df['Names'].str.contains(f'texas'), df.Value * Coefic)` or `df.Value = df.Value.where(~df['Names'].str.contains(f'texas'), df.Value * Coefic)` or `df.Value = np.where(df['Names'].str.contains(f'texas'), df.Value * Coefic, df.Value)` or `df.loc[df['Names'].str.contains(f'texas'), ['Value']] = df.Value * Coefic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df['Value']=np.where(df.Names.str.contains('texas'),df['Value'].astype(int)*10,df['Value'])
df
```